# What is best fitting Regular Expression for CSS values?

Tags: javascript, css, regex, parsing

I have a **Regular Expression** for parsing CSS values, like,

#### In:

```
background: red;
```

#### Out:

```
red
```

I'm using a [CSS Parser NPM Module](https://github.com/reworkcss/css), that uses **CSSOM**. I have found some bugs on this module's parsing system. I decided to fix these bugs myself.

#### What are the bugs?

I'm parsing the CSS of this [URL](https://bizimada.com.tr/Content/css), and it parses only **25 @media rule** of **71 @media rule**,

This bug is caused by,

https://github.com/reworkcss/css/blob/master/lib/parse/index.js#L227 , Regular Expression of module's parsing system.

```
/^((?:'(?:\\'|.)*?'|"(?:\\"|.)*?"|\([^\)]*?\)|[^};])+)/
```

I made this Regular Expression, to

```
/^((?:'(?:\\'|.)*?'|"(?:\\"|.)*?"|[^};])+)/
```

and this problem solved well, parser gave **71 @media rules**. After some tests to other websites' CSS Documents, I found another bug again, in this [URL](http://s.dogannet.tv/q/s/player/html5/1.19.5/assets/css/docs.min.css), and it parses wrong this **value of property** (src property in @font-face rule)

```
url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAA54AAoAAAAAFmgAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABPUy8yAAAA9AAAAD4AAABWUZFeBWNtYXAAAAE0AAAAOgAAAUriMBC2Z2x5ZgAAAXAAAAouAAAPUFvx6AdoZWFkAAALoAAAACsAAAA2DIPpX2hoZWEAAAvMAAAAGAAAACQOogcgaG10eAAAC+QAAAAPAAAAfNkAAABsb2NhAAAL9AAAAEAAAABAMMg06m1heHA...) format("truetype");font-weight:400;font-style:normal}
```

Live RegExr result for the above Input for Changed RegExp: [RegExr](https://regexr.com/465fl)

Live RegExr result for the above Input for Original RegExp of module: [RegExr](https://regexr.com/465g1)

#### So what?

If, I don't change the original RegExp of Module, it makes some wrong outputs and when I change the RegExp, the output is well but some another bugs happen.

I need a better RegExp for this problem, thanks!

Comment: The complete grammar of CSS is almost certainly not regular, so regular expressions aren't powerful enough. You need a real parser.

Comment: @Barmar you can use regex if you're absolutely sure of the CSS (and HTML also), no?

Comment: I tried, CSSOM, but the CSSOM has some wrong issues like, `@charset` rule problems. Think like we have a CSS starting with, `@charset "UTF-8"; body { color: red }...`, when I parse this CSS with CSSOM, the first rule's declaration is: `@charset "UTF-8"; body`. I tried all other parsers like, CSS, CSSOM, JSDOM, JSCSSP and others. Do you have any idea to what i should to do? I'm fighting with CSS parsers for 7 days...